Error saving meeting data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type') in node js in oracledb 6.5.0 version
while inserting data received from frontend to the Database table i am facing this issue even there is no mismatch and any typeos in column name and datatype. error message:Error saving meeting data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')
I am expecting this data would be stored in db

share you code for insert into db

Yes, a test case is needed to understand.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
